# How to disable the leader key in vim insert mode

Tags: vim

I mapped the `leader` key in vim to `<Space>` and I set `timeoutlen` to 250 to have time to use shortcuts with the `leader` key.

But, this is annoying in insert mode, because when I hit space, there is a small delay before the space is added (even though I did not set a binding using the leader key in insert mode) and I sometimes use a shortcut without meaning to.

Is there a way to disable the leader key in insert mode?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The leader key is not special *at all*: if you don't use it in any mapping it works *exactly* like any other key.

Think of `<leader>` as some kind of constant that is automatically expanded to its current value when it is used. When Vim sources your `vimrc` and sees something like:

```
nnoremap <leader>b :ls<CR>:b
```

it will use the current value of `mapleader` and actually do:

```
nnoremap <Space>b :ls<CR>:b
```

What causes the delay you are observing is the fact that `<Space>` is used (via the `<leader>` mechanism in your case) at the beginning of an insert mode mapping: Vim is simply waiting a bit to see if you actually want to insert a `<Space>` or trigger one of the registered insert mode mappings starting with `<Space>`.

To see what insert mode mappings use your `<leader>` and where they come from, do:

```
:verbose imap <leader>
```

If the culprit is defined by a plugin, search its documentation for a way to unmap it.

Comment: Thanks. I found the plugin defining the mappings with the `verbose` command.

Comment: Once you've found the culprits you can make a folder `~/.vim/after/plugin` and put a new file in there called something like `unmap.vim`. In this file you can put unmap commands. One of mine are `iunmap <Leader>is` which is a mapping from `a.vim`.